# Return NSTextfield to Global Variable

Tags: swift, function, struct, nstextfield

My code is supposed to take a user text entry (the IP address of a smart TV), create a variable that's inputted into a function called "triggerRemoteControl".

What's wrong?

I read that global variables are declared as structs, so I made this:

```
struct UserVariables {
static var IPAddress = "http://192.168.2.7/sony/IRCC?"
}
```

Next I outletted a NSTextfield and created an action for it, too:

```
@IBOutlet weak var UIPAddress: NSTextField!
@IBAction func getIP(_ sender: NSTextField) {
let IPAddress = String(UIPAddress.text)

}
```

And then finally:

```
func triggerRemoteControl(irccc: String) {
Alamofire.request(UserVariables.IPAddress,
                  method: .post …
```

Comment: What is the second snippet supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to be an outlet from Interface Builder in Xcode for a textfield, and a function when text is entered? I don't know how to get a 'return' command, or 'know' when the user has finished typing..

Comment: There are notifications `textDidEndEditing` when the user presses return or tab and `textDidChange` when the user presses a(nother) key. Implement the methods and set the delegate of the text field to the target class in Interface Builder.